# XML Schema - child element valid or not dependent on the parent

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to write an XML schema for following conditions:

I have HTML-like XML. If "b" tag is the child of "p", "li", "cell" etc it can have a child element "footnote". It can also have other child "b" tags nested in it.
But if it is a child of "ht" tag the "footnote" is forbidden in its child tree.

For example:

```
<p><b>text<footnote>footnote text</footnote><b>double bold</b>more text</p>

<p><b>text<b>double <footnote>footnote text</footnote> bold</b></p>
```

are valid and

```
<ht><b>text<footnote>footnote text</footnote><b>double bold</b></ht>

<ht><b>text<b>double <footnote>footnote text</footnote> bold</b> more text</ht>
```

is not.
I could override the "b" tag in "ht", but it can have nested "b" in it, so I would have to set a maximum depth. Could I forbid the use of "footnote" in "ht" child tree by an XPath or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with XSD 1.0. You have to use a different schema language, or augment your XSD 1.0 with Schematron.

XSD 1.1 could also help you, since it now supports XPath based assertions; unfortunately, at this time XSD 1.1 support is confined to Xerces (in beta, free) and Saxon EE (full blown, comercial) and definitely is not widely used yet.